# Can anyone share the complete pdf of bramhanda purana. i've came across many websites but it doesn't contain the full brahanda purana

Tags: scripture, puranas, sanskrit, lalita, lalita-sahasranama

Can anyone share the complete PDF of bramhanda Purana in Sanskrit or Telugu. I've came across many websites but they doesn't contain the full bramhanda Purana with Bandasura vada story.i want to read it.

Comment: they were all English translation,but i need the Telugu/Sanskrit  document.thanks for  reacting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the whole Samskrit text at this link - https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.487023/page/n454/mode/2up

For your convenience, the story dealing with Bhandasura starts at the 11th chapter (in page 454 in the book inside that link) of Lalitopakhyana, in which his birth is explained. The very next chapter has the details of birth of Lalita Parameshvari as well. The exact killing of Bhandasura, however, is explained at the 29th chapter (page 509). All these stories are narrated by Lord Hayagriva to sage Agastya. That is why these parts are also called as "Hayagriva Samvaada".

Hope this was useful

Comment: please do explain some part of what you found so it can be generally understood by prakash.

Comment: tq so much this helps me a lot